# Directly proving the extensionality principle for product types without quasi-inverses

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

In section 2.6 of the Univalent Foundations Project's [Homotopy Type Theory book](https://hott.github.io/book/hott-online-1353-g16a4bfa.pdf), the extensionality principle of product types is proven by showing that for all elements $a:A$, $a':A$, $b:A$, $b':A$, the function

$\mathrm{pair}^{=}(a, b, a', b'):((a =_A a') \times (b =_B b')) \to ((a, b) =_{A \times B} (a', b'))$

has a quasi-inverse of

$(\mathrm{ap}_{\mathrm{pr}_1}, \mathrm{ap}_{\mathrm{pr}_2})(c, c'):(c =_{A \times B} c') \to ((\mathrm{pr}_1(c) =_A \mathrm{pr}_1(c')) \times (\mathrm{pr}_2(c) =_B \mathrm{pr}_2(c')))$

with $c \equiv (a, b)$ and $c' \equiv (a', b')$.

Now, how would one directly show that the fiber of $\mathrm{pair}^{=}$ at all identities $p:(a, b) =_{A \times B} (a', b')$ is contractible, without using quasi-inverses? This becomes important in presentations of the product type as a positive type, where one doesn't have the projections $\mathrm{pr}_1$ and $\mathrm{pr}_2$ defined in the elimination rules.

Comment: If you're just concerned about inductively defined products vs. projections, then following the encode-decode method will allow you to define a quasi-inverse to $\mathsf{pair}^=$. You could also define the projections and prove the η rule by induction, which I think is good enough for the projection-based quasi-inverse. Quasi-inverses are mainly used because the coherence necessary to turn them into half-adjoint equivalences is often tedious to define, and because they are often easier to construct than the fiber-based equivalences.

Comment: The products used in the HoTT Book *are* positive.  Look at section 1.5.